# Recommendation for approach regarding How to Dial multiple outbound calls and assign them to specific Agents through a Call Manager

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I've been working with twilio for providing calling solution in Node.js. I need a suggestion in captioned scenario. At high level I want to develop a call manager that is able to dial multiple calls to clients depending upon availability of available agents. Say 10 agents are available now so the call manager fetch list of 10 customers and dial call to them and once connected the call is transferred to one of the 10 agents and so on. Need suggestion how to implement the feature and what twilio APIs to use to achieve the task.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: One solution might be to check after a certain time interval how many agents are available. Accordingly fetch same number of client numbers from some list and start dialing calls. If call is picked up by customer (use status call back for join call (advise me if there is some other method available to check whether customer picked or hangup the call)) then park it in some queue (if queue is available for parking outbound calls) and immediately dial the available agent and connect this call with client's call which is already parked in queue. The scenario can provide bulk calling utility.

Comment: This sounds great, I'd start work on it and then hit up Stack Overflow if you find you have a specific problem. Check out [this article on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok. thanks I'll do that meanwhile needed your suggestion regarding any use case that seems near to my situation. If not can twilio queue resource be used for outbound calling.

Comment: You can put any live call into a queue using the `<Enqueue>queue name</Enqueue>` TwiML element. To dial the top person of a queue, then use `<Dial><Queue>queue name</Queue></Dial>`. I suggest you take a read through the [TwiML documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/) to familiarise yourself with these bits.

Comment: Thanks philnash. I'll check the documentation you suggested.